# How to determine if it's the first time the view has been rendered

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, orm

When my user registers successfully in the website, He will be redirected to his profile page like this:- **domain.com/u/{username}** , So how do I know that the profile view has been loaded/viewed by the user for the first time, So I can but some guidance in his profile to let him know how to edit or use some functionalities in his profile?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this by storing unique `userid` in browser `localstorage` or `cookie`, check onload if userid not exists then show it for first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I handle it:

Add a column to your `user table` called `profile_viewed` that is of type integer, defaut(0);

```
$table->integer('profile_viewed')->default(0);
```

In your controller method set that value to `1` when you render the view:

```
public function profile(User $user)
{
    $user->profile_viewed = 1;
    $user->save();

    //logic to render the view
}
```